# Intel TBB on Win CE for developing mobile applications?

Tags: windows-ce, tbb

i want to know whether we can use INTEL TBB for developing mobile applications on Window CE. i was searching for the material but unable to found any .Basically two things i want to know whether Window CE support for INTEL TBB is there or not . And Whether TBB is suitable  for developing Mobile Applications. Please Help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows CE is not supported by Intel(R) Threading Building Blocks. and Yes TBB supports for developing mobile applications.Intel® Threading Building Blocks (Intel® TBB, threadingbuildingblocks.org) is used to implement the parallelism; the parallel calculation engine can be easily ported to other mobile or desktop platforms.